# oracle triggers firing order (collision, and deadclock )

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have 2 insert triggers, that fire on same table, they both try to alter table row content and then happens collision, or my sql developer starts endless execution of the commands, and then I need to restart DB. How to fix that? Should I merge those 2 triggers into 1 trigger? Or should try to control firing order with this command:

```
execute immediate 'alter trigger trigger_name disable';
execute immediate 'alter trigger trigger_name enable';
```

or should I use trigger inside of trigger.. please I want expert opinion about this one.. im in big dilema right now, since this is the first time I do PL/SQL coding.

**EDIT: HERE ARE THE TRIGGERS WITH WHICH I WORK ON:**

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TRG_PROCED_SN_INS_CENA
AFTER INSERT ON STAVKA_NARUDZBENICE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
pragma autonomous_transaction;
sifra_narudzbenice NUMBER;
BEGIN
paket_sn_sifnar.sifra_narudzbenice := :NEW.sifra_narudzbenice;
pStavkaNarudzbeniceInsert(paket_sn_sifnar.sifra_narudzbenice); 
COMMIT;
END;
/

create or replace
TRIGGER TRG_SN_INS_UPD_NAZIV
AFTER INSERT ON Stavka_narudzbenice
FOR EACH ROW
FOLLOWS TRG_PROCED_SN_INS_CENA
DECLARE
v_naziv_proizvoda VARCHAR2(25);
v_cena NUMBER;
BEGIN  
SELECT naziv_proizvoda INTO v_naziv_proizvoda 
FROM proizvod 
WHERE sifra_proizvoda=:NEW.sifra_proizvoda;
SELECT cena INTO v_cena
FROM stavka_kataloga 
WHERE sifra_proizvoda=:NEW.sifra_proizvoda;
UPDATE stavka_narudzbenice
SET naziv_proizvoda = v_naziv_proizvoda, cena = v_cena WHERE sifra_proizvoda =:NEW.sifra_proizvoda;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 11G you can control the order of triggers using the [FOLLOWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/create_trigger.htm#CJADDIIC) clause.  For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg1
AFTER INSERT ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END;

CREATE TRIGGER trg2 
AFTER INSERT ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
FOLLOWS trg1
BEGIN
...
END;
```

i.e. There are 2 triggers trg1 and trg2 that both fire after insert on table EMP, and we have declared that trg2 should fire after (follow) trg1.

Comment: yea i use 11g database, so this is execution trigger inside trigger ?

Comment: or will trg1 in your example execute after trigger EMP finish execution?

Comment: Mutating tables error concerns the nature of what you are doing in these triggers.

Comment: tony you are right on that one :) can i paste all my code with and can you check where is the error. Im brainstorming 2 days, cant figure it out. :) i updated my code in the question, please check it out.

Comment: Your second trigger updates the table it is fired on, which is probably the cause of your mutating table error.  If it is just trying to update the row it fired on it should not use an update statement; otherwise, it needs to be coded differently - see http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936

Comment: I agree with DCookie - avoid triggers altogether if possible!

Comment: yes yes, its supposed to edit the row witch fired it. ok tony thanks for the information and thank you very much for your time and dedication to help me.

Comment: In that case it should be a BEFORE trigger and should just **assign** the value like this: `:NEW.naziv_proizvoda = v_naziv_proizvoda;`

Comment: man i wanna hug you... :) thank you so much. so thats the way to update row that fired trigger, an i wanted to put update command into another trigger to do the same job. just a small correction, that can help other readers here `:NEW.naziv_proizvoda := v_naziv_proizvoda;` two dots are missing next to equal sign, but thats minor mistake. I really feel privileged to be able to talk to an oracle expert like you. Thanks thanks thanks and once again thanks!!!! @Tony Andrews .

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the order in which statement level triggers fire. Your best bet is to combine the two into one trigger. Even better, avoid the use of triggers if at all possible.

Comment: i can't avoid use of triggers, its a school project, we all do by book.. triggers are needed in this case. So you suggest to merge them into one trigger?

Comment: Then you'll have to combine them.

Comment: And keep in mind that this is an academic exercise, and in real life one should strive mightily to avoid them. The problems you're experiencing should be a lesson as to what can happen with triggers.

Comment: Yea, i lost 2 days on them , believe it or not trying to figure out how they work. I think i would faster done it with hard core programming technique in application, then letting triggers to do job instead of me. :)

Comment: Having said my piece on the evils of triggers, I have to say that you *should* understand how they work and learn the occasions where they are appropriate.